# Rollback a @Transactional annotated method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

Good day. The following code:

```
 class A{
     private B b;
    @Transactional
    public SomeResult doSomething(){
        SomeResult res = null;
        try {
          // do something 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            res  = b.saveResult();
        }
        return res ;
    }
}
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
class B{
  public SomeResult saveResult(){
      // save in db 
  }
}
```

As I understand, if there is an exception in the method `doSomething` the transaction isn't rolled back. And how to make that it rolled? and returned SomeResult

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You shouldn't call Rollback programmatically. The best way, as recommended by the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back), is to use declarative approach. To do so, you need to annotate which exceptions will trigger a Rollback.

In your case, something like this

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor={MyException.class, AnotherException.class})
public SomeResult doSomething(){
   ...
}
```

Take a look at the [@Transaction API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) and the docs about [rolling back a transaction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back).

If, despite the docs recommendation, you want to make a programmatic rollback, then you need to call it from `TransactionAspectSupport` as already suggested. This is from the docs:

```java
public void resolvePosition() {
  try {
    // some business logic...
  } catch (NoProductInStockException ex) {
    // trigger rollback programmatically
    TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
  }
}
```

There may be a architecture mistake though. If your method fails and you need to throw an exception, you shouldn't expect it to return anything. Maybe you're giving too much responsibilities to this method and should create a separated one that only model data, and throws an exception if something goes wrong, rolling back the transaction. Anyway, read the docs.

Comment: `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();` still throws an exception! How can I return something from my transactional method?

Comment: to use TransactionAspectSupport, you must ensure there is no @Transactional on the method/classs, unfortunately. This is a hack. A new method would be cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

get TransactionStatus using TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus() 
ect transaction manager to your bean try to invoke Rollback(DefaultTransactionStatus status) in transaction manager.

refer to spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative)

> You are strongly encouraged to use the declarative approach to
>   rollback if at all possible. Programmatic rollback is available should
>   you absolutely need it, but its usage flies in the face of achieving a
>   clean POJO-based architecture.