# Rollback transaction in spring programmatically

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

My question is rather simple, I would like to rollback a transaction created with `@Transactional` on a method and still be able to return some results to the invoker.

```
@Transactional
public Object myMethod () {
    ...
    // flag transaction for rollback
    return myObject;
}
```

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194891/rollback-a-transactional-annotated-method) which seemed to suggest to either throw an exception  (not really what I am looking for) or invoke `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();`, but eventually this also throws an exception (I am using JpaTransactionManager).

Any idea how I could achieve my goal?

Comment: How about using a Spring TransactionTemplate and handling the Transaction 'manually'.

Comment: Maybe `TransactionAspectSupport.getTransactionManager().rollback(TransactionStatus)`?

Comment: We've solved a similar problem by throwing a custom Exception that wraps the result, but we don't really like it as well. Using Exceptions as regular control flow is very ugly.

Comment: Are you by change using Hibernate behind? If so you could access the `SessionFactory` to get and rollback the current transaction.

Comment: @Marvin I am using EclipseLink, but I am oretty sure that if you bypass the TM, it will lead to other problems, so I wouldn't go that way.

Comment: Yes - you would have to work with the `TransactionSynchronizationManager`, but it's certainly doable. What I'm not so certain about is that there will be a solution other than the ones already mentioned which won't cause problems. Maybe you can take a step back and think about your architecture (to get rid of the "rollback AND return value" requirement at this point)?

Comment: @Marvin Technically speaking there is no other way to go than using a transaction and roll it back. The actions are the following: do some changes in a transaction, query the DB to check the validity of the data and then according to the results, choose to roll back or not, eventually report some feedback on the outcome and possible reasons of failure.

Answer (score 1):

Before changing the data in DB, I always validate it. Because data must be valid when persisting the changes, I consider a correct behaviour to throw an exception (for the case of invalid data).

On the other hand, if you do not want to validate the data explicitly before persisting it, throw an overriden Exception that contain other fields that you need.

PS: In my logic I consider that rolling back a transaction has a critical cause, *other than* that data is not valid.

---

Trying to validate the data and to persist it in DB *in the same service method* seems to me bad design. Imagine you want to return back a container with validation messages if validation fails or to return a new entity, if the transaction was correct. What return type should your method have?

Comment: I perform a few updates and then identify (or not) an invalid situation. I want to rollback the changes I made and return meaningful info, so no reason, for me at least, to throw an exception. Throwing an exception for normal business flow feels just plain wrong, without ading to the fact that it is very ugly an unefficient.

Comment: I see two possibilities: either you "are lazy" and an Exception gets thrown (either by you or by Spring), or you validate the data and not even try to persist the data. As I understand, you COULD validate the data (before performing those updates), but you don't, am I right?

Comment: The only way to validate the data is by issuing select calls on the DB because it involve queries over thousands of rows, so validating up-front is not an option.

Comment: Why not validating it only once (and not again on persist)? If you issue only SELECT-queries (and do not change any data), why bother to rollback the transaction?

Comment: First I issue a few inserts and updates, then I do some select to validate the data, and eventually I want to return a response object indicating that it either succeeded or failed, and in case of failure, I provide additional info on why it failed

Comment: "In case of failure": how do you identify a failure (can you be more specific)? is that DB related? May be you simply need to add a constraint on DB level in order to constraint your data?

Comment: I have to issue several queries to the db and verify that I don't get any rows back for those queries. The query can sbe complex and involve joins and hierarchical queries, so it's not doable in-memory. I oul likno voi lying on DB  constraints as they are harder to control and could slow the application

Comment: I think you are afraid of Exception only because of their inneficiency. Can you estimate your failure rate? Beside I think you could delegate the final part of your validation to the DB level (with constraints)...

Comment: I am not afraid of Exception, it just feels plain wrong to use them for a normal situation. It makes my code ugly and not natural. Yet, for the moment  it's  the only working  solution I have. I am only trying to see if there's an actual good way to do this with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
```

It will rollback after leaving. But beware:

```
@Transactional
public void save(){
   trySave();
}
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
private void trySave(){
   ...
}
```

This will ignore the `readOnly` because the transaction-block starts in `save()`!

Comment: Beware in optimistic propagation.

Comment: Not sure we can safely rely on the readOnly flag according to the doc. It's barely a hint to the TM.